# how to add image in shepherd.js steps?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add img in shepherd JS.

I tried adding the `<img />` tag directly in the text field of steps. but it didn't work.

```
export const journalSteps = [
  {
    id: 'intro',
    title: 'Welcome Nahid',
    text: (
      <img
        alt="tour.png"
        src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5378891/197385811-55df8480-7ff4-44bd-9d43-a7dade598d70.png"
      />
    ),
    attachTo: {
      element: '.journal-tour-start-point',
      on: 'right'
    },
    cancelIcon: {
      enabled: true
    },
    buttons: [
      {
        classes: backBtnClass,
        text: 'Back',
        type: 'back'
      },
      {
        classes: nextBtnClass,
        text: 'Next',
        type: 'next',
        next: function () {
          instance.hide();
        }
      }
    ],
    classes: 'tour-test-class-1'
  },

  {
    title: 'Please Click on Step 2',
    attachTo: {
      element: '.first-step-62',
      on: 'left'
    },
    cancelIcon: {
      enabled: true
    },
    buttons: [
      {
        classes: backBtnClass,
        text: 'Back',
        type: 'back'
      },
      {
        classes: nextBtnClass,
        text: 'Next',
        type: 'next'
      }
    ],
    text: ['Please Click On .']
  }
];
```

I want to add image in each steps.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close.
The text key is expecting a 'string' data type.
The best method I've found is to use a template literal to wrap the all of the HTML you want to place as children of the text object with the 'shepherd-text' class. This enables your input to be a string and allows you to import and dynamically set the image source.

```
import image from "../assets/image.gif";

const steps = [
    {
         id: "tour-step",
         title: "Tour Step",
         text: `<div class="tour-text-container">
                    <div class="image-container">
                        <img 
                            src=${image}
                            class="imageStyle"
                            frameBorder="0" 
                            allowFullScreen
                        >
                        </img>
                    </div>
                </div>`
    }
]
```

Hope this helps!